# Count how many rows has value in bindingsource

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, bindingsource

I have a column that has multiple rows with the same value. I want to find how many rows there is that has the search term.

My code so far

```
Dim foundindex As Integer
foundindex = Me.ProcessLogBindingSource.Find("HS", HSbox.Text.ToUpper)
msgbox(foundindex)
```

But this always returns a value of 1. I presume it stops searching once it finds the first row with the search term in. How do i get it to count how many rows has it in?

Using VB.Net in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter) an then use the `Count`-property:

```
Me.ProcessLogBindingSource.Filter = "HS = '" & HSbox.Text & "'"
MsgBox(Me.ProcessLogBindingSource.Count)
```

Comment: I get :System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Double.' on the first line. HSbox.text is a string